# Repeat list using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following list with an image number and folder number which I want to repeat it 27 time - only want to change the image number and have the ability to set the folder number.

```
    <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" checked="checked" /> <img src="assets/images/personal_images/folder1/0001.png" /></li>
    <li><input type="radio" checked="checked" /> <img src="assets/images/personal_images/folder1/0002.png" /></li>
    <li><input type="radio" checked="checked" /> <img src="assets/images/personal_images/folder1/0003.png" /></li>
</ul>
```

I have the following code I'm playing about with:

```
  var RepeatModule = React.createClass({
      getDefaultProps: function() {
        return { items: [] }
      },
      render: function() {

        var listItems = this.props.items.map(function(item) {
          return (
            <li key="{item}">
               <input type="radio" checked="checked" /> 
               <img src="assets/images/personal_images/folder1/000' + {item} + '.png" />
            </li>
          );
        });

        return (
            <ul>
              {listItems}
            </ul>
        );
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I cam up with.. It repeats 27 times and allows the folder to be passed in as a prop just like you wish.

```
var RepeatModule = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      folder: 'folder1'
    }
  },
  render: function() {

    // Build your 27 items here in to an array
    // you can also pass in 27 items as props but a for loop is a great way to get exactly 27 things.
    var items = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 27; i++) {
      items.push({
        image: 'assets/images/personal_images/' + this.props.folder + '/000' + i + '.png'
      })
    }

    return (
      <ul>
      {
        // map over the array here and display your list items
        (items).map(function(item, key) {
          return (
            <li key={key}>
              <input type="radio" checked="checked" /> 
              <img src={item.image} />
            </li>
          )
        })
      }
      </ul>
    );
  }
});
```

You can see this working (with broken images) here: https://jsbin.com/koripebake/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Although you *could* do it the way you mentioned, it'd be better to split this into two components.

```
var List = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
  var list = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
    list.push(<ListItem key={i} />);
  }
    return (
        <ul>
          {list}
        </ul>
    );
  }
});
```

and

```
var ListItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <li>
          <input type="radio" checked="checked" /> 
          <img src={'assets/images/personal_images/folder1/000' + this.props.key + '.png'} />
        </li>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: was indents meant to be list?